# How can I upload an image in a PHP form with other attributes

Tags: php, html, blob, image-uploading

I have been trying to upload an image including other attributes in a html form using PHP, the code below sort of works but when i submit the form after choosing the file from a directory. I can see the file in my database BLOB column but the name of the file in the image_name column of my database is a series of characters which I think is Binary .

see Code below any suggestions will be helpful and also I would like to display the saved image in an echo something like echo '' if that is possible

```
//connect to db

include 'connect.php';


//$random = rand(23456789,98765432);

$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if (!isset($file))
echo "Please select an image.";
else {
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents ($_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name']));
$image_name = addslashes ($_FILES['image'] ['name']);
$image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

if ($image_size==FALSE)
echo "That is not an image.";

else 
{
if (!$query = mysql_query ("INSERT into events VALUES     ('','$event_type','$title','$description','$date','$location','$image_name','$image','$add1','$add2','$city','$postcode','$country','$tick')"))

echo "Problem uploading image";


}





}
```

Comment: try to upload your file to some directory of your website and only send filename in the databse..so when echoing image you can use your normal html and in src attribute provide the path of the directory and the file name from database..

Comment: addslashes is completely the wrong function to use here – go read up on what is _actually_ to be done against SQL injection. And the MySQL functions are deprecated, you should be using MySQLi instead.

Comment: @Muhammad How do I set the directory in the code above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure your form has: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

then use:

'move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"uploads/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);'

Comment: Hi @muhammad that worked for me . However i do have another problem, I am trying to echo the image from the image column . my code is below :


<?php
include 'connect.php';
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$image = addslashes ($_REQUEST['image']);
$image = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM events");
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
$image = $image['image'];



echo $image;



?>

I to echo this file as "get" in a html <img src ='get.php'>

please help

Comment: i think you need to change your insert query first.. just insert the name of your image file into the database an then retrieve the name from database.. and display your image using `<img src='uploads/'.$image_name_from_the_database_with_extension>` and save your image name using the below code inthe comment

Comment: `$path = "uploads/someImage.png";` `$file = basename($path);`  then echo $file

Comment: Wouldn't this create a problem if there are multiple images with the same name in the database ?

Comment: good question.. for that you need to check it from the database every time user submits the forms.. well i would like to suggest you to use `Codeigniter` framework for php..